# Xpath get only text node not others nodes of element

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I have have the follow structure:

```
<div class="xGh">
    <div class="xg1">
        <div>I need that text<br><br>
            <span>That no</span><br>
            <span>Nope</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i try that:

```
<?php
$xg1 = $xpath->query('//div[@class="xg1"]/*[1]');

for($i = 0; $i < $xg1 ->length; $i++)
{    echo "xg1  :".$xg1->item($i)->nodeValue."<br/>";
}
?>
```

The problem that return all text with other text too, like :

```
xg1 : I need that textThat noNope
```

I need:

```
xg1 : I need that text
```

<sub>Sry my bad english</sub>

Comment: SimpleXML or DOM?

Comment: tks for atention, Dom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you should need to do is normalize all the whitespace for the `text()` childnodes of your first-child (`div`).

This should do

```
$xg1 = $xpath->query('//div[@class="xg1"]/*[1]/text()[normalize-space()]');
```

That should give you one `DOMText` node in the `DOMNodeList`.

Comment: uau homem, perfeito, onde tem referência para aprender que mintueness xpath? GG HF tks I could never get that `normalize`

Comment: @MagicHat Well, all you were really missing was `text()` for the node in question which would have eliminated all the other child-node text. You still would have got all the whitespace and there's plenty of answers for that issue on StackOverflow :) See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space

Comment: have u some tip with that xpath question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47048955/extract-value-from-background-image-style-attribute-with-xpath look the error https://ideone.com/NoSAAE